# UK Rail Season Ticket and Intermediate Stations

Tags: uk, trains, tickets, national-rail

Suppose I have a UK rail season ticket for journeys between stations `A` and `D` on the following line:

`---A---B---C---D---`

Can I use the same season ticket to make the following journeys:

- `A` to `B`
- `C` to `D`
- `B` to `C`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Or even, "Yes, yes and yes."

The [National Rail Conditions of Carriage](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/static/documents/content/NRCOC.pdf) allow all these journeys. Season tickets are unrestricted (other than by route), so I haven't reproduced the conditions relating to restricted tickets.

> 16. Starting, breaking or ending a journey at intermediate stations
>
>     You may start, or break and resume, a journey (in either direction in the case of a return 
>       ticket) at any intermediate station, as long as the ticket you hold is valid for the trains you 
>       want to use. You may also end your journey (in either direction in the case of a return 
>       ticket) before the destination shown on the ticket.